# Google Cloud Build & Firebase Deploy - "An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Build to do a deployment to Firebase Hosting when a commit is on master. I'm using the [Firebase](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/firebase) Cloud Builder, deployed to my project. I've checked permissions in the Cloud Console and Firebase access is enabled.

Everything seems to go well in generating the static HTML for hosting, but at the final build step it fails suddenly with this problem:

`Error: An unexpected error has occurred.`

Here is the step in my cloudbuild.yaml that fails:

```
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase
  args: ['deploy', '--project', '$PROJECT_ID']
  id: Deploy to Firebase
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time that I installed the container was in October. The "An unexpected error has occurred" was solved by others by updating their version of the Firebase CLI. I had to do the same thing in my CD environment in order to get this to work.

Following these instructions [in the README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community):

```
cd cloud-builders-community/firebase
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

The Firebase CLI version was reinstalled and published to my project. Then I was able to retry the build and it worked successfully.

This tripped me up for about an hour yesterday, and I thought it may be helpful to just have the answer documented somewhere.