# Unexpected Error on Google Cloud Build Deploy to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build, firebase-cli

I have previously managed to deploy small projects to firebase hosting with google cloud build. My current project includes functions, but my deploy script is --only:hosting

I understand this is similar to these posts: [stackoeverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607465/cannot-deploy-from-gcp-cloud-build-to-firebase-hosting) [stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754674/google-cloud-built-not-substituting-environment-variable-for-firebase-token/55762821#55762821) and [stackoverflow3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552244/google-cloud-build-firebase-deploy-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred) - but I am using functions and kms not secrets, and I have logged in to firebase ci to get my token. Nothing I've seen points the way clearly enough so far!

I am using google kms cryptography and all my permissions are set up correctly. Correct accounts have firebase admin permissions. Trigger variables are defined correctly.

My .env file contains a parameter FIREBASE_TOKEN that I got by doing firebase login:ci

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
    # Install
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
      args: ['install']
    # Build
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
      args: ['run', 'build']
    #Decrypt
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      args: ['kms', 'decrypt', '--ciphertext-file=.env.enc', '--plaintext-file=.env', '--location=global', '--keyring=$_KEY_RING', '--key=$_KEY']
    # Deploy
    - name: 'gcr.io/$_PROJECT_ENV/firebase'
      args: ['deploy', '--debug', '--token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN', '--only=hosting:$_DEPLOY_TO', '--project', '$_PROJECT_ENV']
```

This runs fine until right at the end, when it gives these messages:

```
Step #3: === Deploying to 'dev-xxxxx'...
Step #3: 
Step #3: i  deploying hosting 
Step #3: 
Step #3: ✔  Deploy complete! 
Step #3: 
Step #3: Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/dev-xxxxx/overview
Step #3: [2020-09-27T15:51:57.341Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined
Step #3:     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:85:36
Step #3:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Step #3: 
Step #3: Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Tearing my hair out trying to find what could possibly be wrong? Not getting any permissions errors and firebase image is the latest and builds fine? Any suggestions?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1232) suggests it might be an issue with `firebase.json` or `.firebaserc`.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to do exactly what you are doing, but I am a bit lost tbh. Could you explain what step #Decrypt is doing, and what should it do to get it working? Any step by step documentation?

Comment: I encrypted with a gcp keyring so that env vars don't get stored unencrypted on git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message might be produced for deployments that don't have the `target` key and value defined in the `firebase.json` file, and for deployments that have incorrect `target` values.

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets#configure_your_firebasejson_file_to_use_deploy_targets):

> In your `firebase.json` file, reference the associated target name when
> you're configuring the settings for each resource or group of
> resources.